# Evaluate $\int x(7-5x^2)^5dx$ using u substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.2

Evaluate $\int x(7-5x^2)^5dx$ using u substitution

Can somebody verify this solution for me?? Thanks

---

Let $u=7-5x^2$. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=-10x$ and so $\frac{du}{-10x}=dx$. Making these substitutions we get:

$\int x(7-5x^2)^5dx$

$=\int x(u)^5 \frac{du}{-10x}$

$=\frac{1}{-10} \int u^5du$

$=\frac{1}{-10} u^6 \frac{1}{6} + C$

$=\frac{-1}{60} u^6 +C$

$= \frac{-1}{60} (7-5x^2)^6 +C$

Comment: Looks fine, well done. Although you can check your own work by differentiating your result.

Comment: If you go from ${du\over dx}=-10x$ to ${du\over-10}=xdx$ instead of ${du\over-10x}=dx$, you can skip a step in the display. But that's just to streamline things a little; your solution is entirely correct as is.